# How to call a function as a parameter, I tried this not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Now I am trying to call a function as a parameter of another function, why is this not working for me, not displaying anything on the screen,
tried doing that inside the callback function, also
dont mind the preventDefault(), just practicing something

```
let button = document.getElementById("dugme");
 function luka() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res("auto");
    rej("kamion");
  });
}
button.addEventListener("submit", (ev, luka) => {
  let bobo = document.getElementById("test");
  if (!bobo) ev.preventDefault();
  else {
    luka()
      .then(info => {
        info = bobo;
        let luna = document.createElement("h1");
        info.innerText = "Bobo je kralj";
        luna.append(info);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
});
```

///////////HTML/////////////

```
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="dugme">Dugme</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying here mate? The `luka()` wont work because you have a local variable named `luka` which overrides the other instance.

Comment: I tired passing the funtion luka from above as a parameter there, so I could call it down, how would u write this code here, to make .then inside in else.

Comment: besides the local variable issue, you never append luna to a dom node so info wont be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call the promise function as a parameter here.
Once it's declared you can simply use it within the other function.

Also, you need to append `luna` to the dom using `document.body.appendChild(luna)`.

Here's the full code:

```
let button = document.getElementById("dugme");
 const luka = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res("auto");
    rej("kamion");
  });
}
button.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  let bobo = document.getElementById("test");
  if (!bobo) ev.preventDefault();
  else {
    luka()
      .then(info => {
        info = bobo;
        let luna = document.createElement("h1");
        info.innerText = "Bobo je kralj";
        luna.append(info);
        document.body.appendChild(luna)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The moment you append info to luna, info is not in the dom anymore as you never append luna (h1 tag) to a node inside the dom so you miss something like:

```
luka()
  .then(info => {
    info = bobo;
    let luna = document.createElement("h1");
    info.innerText = "Bobo je kralj";
    luna.append(info);
    document.body.appendChild(luna); // <-- this is missing
  })
```

edit: as mentioned in above comment. There is also the issue with overwriting you luka function. Given the assumption you solve this naming clash, my solution here would be still applicable.